# Mysql encoding in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I'm having issue with MySql encoding using the hebrew language.
Table has charset utf8 and collation utf8_unicode_ci
and the varchar columns are also set as utf8 and utf8_unicode_ci.
I have a stored procedure that insert rows into the table using stored procedure variables.

The problem is that I get question marks in the `name` field which means it's an encoding problem.
The sp variable:

```
SET GroupName= CONCAT(subjectName,' כיתה ',GetClassName(classCode),'\' ',classNum)
```

The query:

```
INSERT INTO mdl_groups (courseid,idnumber,name,timecreated) VALUES (cid,GIdNumber,GroupName,UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

I tried some of the solutions suggested in other threads like setting collation to `utf8_general_ci` or setting `SET NAMES 'utf8';` before the query but this is not helping.

Please help! thanks

Comment: Data does not become corrupted on its own. Who puts the question marks in the fields?

Comment: I updated my question with example of the query